# Network connection problem in react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to run react native app on android using expo cli. But getting this network connection error.[network connection problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O2pn.jpg)
Image is available on the above link.

Comment: Try to set the Expo to use a tunnel rather than your local network

Comment: Tried using tunnel too. Still showing the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in expo, if you are in development mode, both mobile and computer should be connected to the same wifi. so it can connect to your localhost.